# How to delete current line in GNU-screen (bash equivalent of Ctrl-K)?

Tags: gnu-screen

In GNU `screen`, the shortcut `Ctrl-A` + `Ctrl-K` or just `K` is mapped to kill the current window. I was wondering is there a shortcut to clear the current characters input so far in the prompt, just like the bash `Ctrl-U` or `Ctrl-A` + `Ctrl-K` would. I haven't been able to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "prompt" you are referring to the GNU screen prompt by Ctrl-A and <kbd>:</kbd>, that gets cleared by Ctrl-U.  That is standard for most command-line applications; the others are bash-specific.

Answer (score 1):

In general, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> is reserved for `screen` itself. So to actually send `Ctrl+A`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>.

In your case, the bash `Ctrl+A` puts the cursor to the beginning of the input line and `Ctrl+K` deletes everything until the end of it. Within `screen`, you want to use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.